# How to test a contract which is generated by another deployed contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

Currently, I want to test a contract called `B` which is generated from another contract `Registry` by using truffle. For example:

Contract `Registry`

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.17;
import "./B.sol";
contract Registry is Owned {

    function createContract(
        address userAddress) 
        public
        returns(
            bool res
        )
    {
        // create a contract B which the owner is the user.
        B b = new B(userAddress);

        return true;
    }
```

Contract `B`

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.17;
contract B {
    address private owner;

    constructor (
        address _owner
    ) 
        public
    {
        owner = _owner;
    }

    function logData(
        bytes32 data,
        uint    timestamp
    )
        public
        returns(bool res)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
```

testing script `B.js` in truffle/test:

```
const Registry = artifacts.require('./Registry.sol');
const B = artifacts.require('./B.sol');

const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');
const assert = require('assert');

contract('Registry', (accounts) => {
  let registry;
  let B;

  beforeEach(async () => {
      // create a reportSummary contract from registry contract. 
      registry = await Registry.deployed();

      // How can I retrieve the contract B's instance?
  });
```

Because I am a newbie in solidity, thus I cannot find any way to test the function `logData` or other functions in contract `B` which depends on the contract `Registry`. Is there any suitable way or should I change the contract designed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my this answer it has example too about accessing the function from imported contract

[Solidity: Can a Parent contract see data updates from a Child contract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655626/solidity-can-a-parent-contract-see-data-updates-from-a-child-contract/55689771#55689771)

To access the function through web3, just use the instance of Registry contract and you can call the function of Contract B

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I still cannot access new and specific contract B (each contract B belongs to one user). Once there are more contract B which has been generated by the Registry contract, how should I know which contract B to be tested?

Comment: It seems like I just deployed contract B with the user's address only is enough to test without considering the registry contract... Thanks.